# How to fix Next.js failing to get page data on /money when run npm run build.?

Tags: next.js

am in next.js 13.4 and when I run npm run build , it's throwing an error saying failed to get page data at /money , but the money page does is not even complex, it's just a component returning a div written money in it. Help me fix,please.

Tried clearing the cache but didn't change anything.

Comment: Hello Clyde! Do you have the code? With the code we can resolve better your problem :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.